# How to get fuzzy matching with helm in describe-*?

Tags: helm, fuzzy-search

I have fuzzy matching in `helm-apropos` with `helm-apropos-fuzzy-match` set to true. I would like to get fuzzy matching for `descibe-function` and `describe-variable` and the like, too. How can I enable it for these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `helm-mode-fuzzy-match` to `t` should do the work. These two just don't have separate options, let the helm maintainer know, if you think it is worth to have.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not limited to Helm for this, and you use [Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles), then *every* command, not just `describe-function` and `describe-variable`, can use fuzzy matching.

To toggle fuzzy matching on, just use `C-(` or `M-(` from the minibuffer, depending on which type of fuzzy matching you want.  Icicles has many types of fuzzy matching, and these keys cycle among matching/completion methods.

See [Icicles -Completion Methods and Styles](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Completion_Methods_and_Styles) for details.